# iOS 10 userNotificationCenter didReceiveNotificationResponse not triggered when app is in background or killed

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, ios10, unusernotificationcenter

The callbacks in UNUserNotificationDelegate are not called at all when the application is in background until user tapped the notification.

every thing is working fine like remote to device notification "willPresentNotification" etc but didReceiveNotificationResponse is only called when user tap on the notification.

---

**Purpose:** i want to implement notifications logs in my app locally using coreData and want to save the notification data exactly when the notification arrives not when user tapped on it...

i have done this perfectly in iOS < 10 but i cant find any delegate functions in iOS 10 that triggered when the notification arrives..

for more Detailed discussion check this thread 
[For iOS 10, will application:didReceiveRe...](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/54322)

Comment: Are you sending a "silent" push notification? `content-available:1`? Or a local notification?

Comment: no im not using content-available:1 in my payload

Comment: A remote notification should be delivered to https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application?language=objc `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` if your app is suspended. If your app is terminated then you do not get any delegate method executing.